# Debugging on Netbeans remote to server

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans

I use Netbeans and debug code with xdebug for debugging php files
that are remote from server. And I config to upload to the server when I save a file in Netbeans.

I work in a team. I download some code that needs to be modified or added. So in Netbeans (in my computer) there are some old files that aren't updated from the server which is caused by people on the team who modified or added files in server.

Example: Server has files `index.php` , `foo.php` , `bar.php`
and my Netbeans has files `index.php` , `foo.php` , `bar.php` too, but `bar.php` in the server is updated by people on the team. But `bar.php` in my Netbeans is old file that isn't updated. So `bar.php` file in server is the newest `bar.php` in my Netbeans

And code in `foo.php` calls function from `bar.php`

**Question** 
If I am debugging in `foo.php` file.

1) Netbean will upload `foo.php` file to server or not.

2) Netbean will upload all files (in Netbeans) to server or not.

3) If Answer 1) and 2) is not. In process debugging. Netbean will compile `bar.php` file from server or Netbeans

Comment: it sounds like youre lives would be made much simpler if you used some kind of version control like GIT or SVN.